# MaskedEditExtender in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, maskededitextender

How can I useMaskedEditExtender for textbox that should accept address of website?
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Why would you use an `MaskedEdit`? I'd use a Textbox with a `RegularExpressionValidator`.

`MaskedEdit` is good for data that has a fixed format across your data domain. For instance the SSID is always in the format `000-00-0000`, a phone number (in U.S.) is `(000) 000-0000`, the new zip code is `00000-0000`. and so forth...

Not for a wide variant of formats like an URL, which is governed by an RFC.

Comment: Just to add to Paulo's answer. Consider two domains- www.somedomain.com, and www.somedomain.co.uk. Obviously unless you were always collecting www.{domain}.com, a MaskedEdit wouldn't work well.

Comment: Agreed.  Validating the control would be more appropriate than using a mask.  I'm sure there's plenty of regular expressions on the 'Net that can validate an Internet URL.